# New "oscillator basis" of gamma matrices?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, differential-geometry, supergravity, dirac-matrices

It was mentioned in http://kclpure.kcl.ac.uk/portal/files/12371620/Studentthesis-Mehmet_Akyol_2013.pdf page 28, a new concept "oscillator basis" or more precisely the author defines *gamma matrices of the oscillator basis*. What does it mean to have gamma matrices of oscillator basis?

The relevant equations from Akyol's paper are:

> The Clifford algebra gamma matrices can also be constructed using these basis
>   elements and are defined in the following way (1.10),$$\Gamma_0 = - e_n \wedge +i_{e_n}$$
>   $$\Gamma_i = e_i\wedge +i_{e_i}$$
>   $$\Gamma_n = e_n \wedge +i_{e_n}$$ 
>   $$\Gamma_{i+n} = i(e_i\wedge -i_{e_i})$$where $i=1, ..., n-1$ where $n=d/2$ in even dimensions. As for (1.31) it is $$\Gamma_{+} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\Gamma_n +\Gamma_0) = \sqrt{2}i_{e_n},$$
>   $$\Gamma_{-} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\Gamma_n - \Gamma_0) =\sqrt{2}e_n \wedge,$$
>   $$\Gamma_{\alpha} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\Gamma_{\alpha} +i\Gamma_{\alpha+n})=\sqrt{2}i_{e_{\alpha}},$$
>   $$\Gamma_{\bar{\alpha}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\Gamma_{\alpha} - i\Gamma_{\alpha+n}) = \sqrt{2}e_{\alpha} \wedge$$
>   Here $d=2n$

If we take $d=4$, then $n=2$ and $i$ takes only the value $1$ we get:

> $$\Gamma_0 = - e^2 \wedge +i_{e^2}$$
>   $$\Gamma_1 = e^1\wedge +i_{e^1}$$
>   $$\Gamma_2 = e^2 \wedge +i_{e^2}$$
>   $$\Gamma_3 = i(e^1\wedge -i_{e^1})$$
>   Where the oscillator Gamma matrices can be written as
>   $$\Gamma_{+} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\Gamma_2 +\Gamma_0) = \sqrt{2}i_{e^2},$$
>   $$\Gamma_{-} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\Gamma_2 - \Gamma_0) =\sqrt{2}e^2 \wedge,$$
>   $$\Gamma_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\Gamma_1 +i\Gamma_3)=\sqrt{2}i_{e^1},$$
>   $$\Gamma_{\bar{1}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\Gamma_1 - i\Gamma_3) = \sqrt{2}e^1 \wedge$$

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: The link is currently dead. It's unclear what this question is asking for. Please exhibit the "gamma matrices of the oscillator basis" *within the question*.

Comment: @ACuriousMind please reconsider the closure, the question as been edited.

Comment: Why exactly did you *remove* the details necessary to understand the question without clicking a link again?

Answer (score 1):

The basis change for the [Clifford algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra)

$$ \{\Gamma_A, \Gamma_B\}_+~=~2\eta_{AB} \tag{1.12} $$

can be viewed as a linear coordinate transformation in the (complexified) Minkowski space$^1$ $V$ of dimension $2n$. The longitudinal and temporal coordinates go into [light-cone coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-cone_coordinates). The transversal coordinates pair up two and two and are transformed in a similar way, see eq. (1.31) for details.

In the new "oscillator basis", the gamma matrices becomes isomorphic to standard Grassmann-odd creation and annihilation operators acting on a fermionic [Fock space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space); or equivalently in a mathematical language, exterior and interior multiplication of degree-one elements in an [exterior algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra).

--

$^1$ Since OP's link ultimately aims at describing (super)gravity in a curved spacetime $M$, we should stress that the vector space $V$ is generally *not* spacetime itself. For each spacetime point $p\in M$ the [vielbein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_formalism_%28physics%29) $e:T_pM \to V$ forms a (vector space) isomorphism with the tangent space $T_pM$ at $p$.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: @Qmechanic I would like to ask you if you may, which are considered as longitudinal,temporal and transversal coordinates? Thank you.

Comment: @PhilosophicalPhysics please update your question because this link is dead. I am requesting this because of the discussion that is going on here (http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/226780/oscillator-null-basis-gamma-matrices?noredirect=1#comment491379_226780).

Comment: @Fluctuations done

Comment: The answer uses the words _longitudinal coordinate, temporal coordinate, transversal coordinates & light-cone coordinates_ in their standard sense (as seen in e.g. E&M). Note that sign conventions, factors of $\sqrt{2}$, and number of spacetime dimensions may differ.

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes, but what about the $1$ and $\bar{1}$, aren't those complex conjugates of one another? They are not plain coordinates. Can you please be a little more elaborate about this basis. I'm confused about the so many debates mentioned by several volunteers on the website, not to mention, the idea of complex null tetrad formalism and its potential to be the one concerned with this basis.